# Use CakePHP routes in shell

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

How is it possible to use `Router::url()` in a shell in CakePHP 2.0/2.1?

Comment: What exactly do you have in mind? The Router is for routing URL's. Shells don't have anything to do with URL's, as they are called from your OS terminal rather than your browser.

Comment: I am doing a cron job which logs some actions. Those actions have some URLs, for easier access when viewing the log, that's why I need to use `Router::url()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Router::url()` in the same way as in your controllers/views. The only thing is if you need full URL, you have to define the full base url constant yourself.

```
    if (!defined('FULL_BASE_URL')) {
        define('FULL_BASE_URL', 'http://example.com');
    }
```

Comment: I think that routes are not added by default in shells, and I couldn't find a way to import them, `App::uses()` doesn't say anything about routes.

Comment: `App::uses('Router', 'Routing');`. If you are unsure about paths, check the cake lib structure, it follows pretty nice for `App:uses()` as well

Comment: I'm having issues with this as well. "fatal error: class 'router'"

Answer (score 1):

use
1. define 
   define('BASE_URL', 'autoauction'); in /app/Config/bootstrap.php
2. $home = Router::url('/', true);
   $this->out($home.BASE_URL);

It will work.